# Linear Operator is $G$-invariant

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

This is from Artin's *Algebra*, ch. $10, 7.4$.

> Prove that the linear operator $T=\sum\limits_{g\in C} \rho_{g}$ is $G$ invariant where $\rho$ is the representation of finite group $G$ and $C$ is the conjugacy class.

Is there a way to prove this by contradiction?

Comment: Why would you want to to this by contradiction? It is a straightforward application of the definitions.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I did try it directly but I was stuck at one place. Hence was trying contradiction. My attempt was consider $Tv$ for a vector $v$. We will have to multiply by $v$ on the right hand side. Now the representation acts on $v$ but there is no further information given. I thought we could somehow relate to the character as the characters are constant over conjugacy classes. So, I was stuck at that point. I am sorry if this is too obvious. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Well, how does $G$ act on the representation $\rho$?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: It would act by left multiplication

Comment: How could it? Left multiplication would be inside $G$. But $\rho$ is not an element of $G$. So given $g\in G$, what is $g\rho$? It should be some representation of $G$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Ahh! I see. Since here we are considering operation of $G$  it would be an operation: (gh)v=g(hv)

Comment: But that does not define the action. That is just something an action needs to satisfy.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: The only other possibility since g is in the conjugacy class will be the conjugation

Comment: I am not asking you to guess how $G$ acts. This should be stated somewhere in the book.